# Ubuntu makes a click noise when restarting

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, playonlinux, restart

I have a problem with Ubuntu

When I restart Ubuntu on my laptop, it makes a click sound (like the sound that comes with forced restart by holding the power button) and then restarts!
My laptop is dual boot Ubuntu/Windows10 and there's no problem with Windows, I think it's apparently a problem with Ubuntu's side...

Can someone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: How old is your laptop?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen The model is  Thinkpad - E570 i7  I think in 2017 was on the market

Comment: To see if this is a hardware issue or a software issue: please press left `Alt` + `SysRq` + `B`. This will reboot the computer without powering down. The `SysRq` key is usually the same as `PrtScrn`.

Comment: Could the click be coming from speaker and not power supply? If you are using TLP there are issues with clicking sounds through speaker.

Comment: @jos ALT+SysRq+B correctly restarted the system. I think the click sound comes from the hard drives head... In any case, this sound is not normal

Comment: you should very quickly back up your data now. your drive could be about to give in any second now and you don't want to take any risks.

Comment: It's because of replacing the optical drive port with a hard drive by using a hdd-caddy.
I had previously upgraded my system to SSD, now I know this is a problem due to the hard drive being installed in the optical drive port.